# How to make my navigation bar show which page i am on

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <!-- end nav collapse button -->
                </button>
                <!-- logo -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Dad's Site</a>

                <!-- end navbar header -->
            </div>
            <!-- start nav collapse -->
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
```

the class active showed aboved does not work correctly. I want it to show a white line or something of that sort underneath the current page
then i would be able to see which nav page i was on depending on which one i had selected

```
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
                        </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">

                        <a href="gallery.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Photo Gallery <span class="caret"></span></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

                            <li><a href="#">Gallery 1</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Gallery 2</a>

                            </li>

                            <li><a href="#">Gallery 3</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Gallery 4</a>

                            </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Gallery 5</a>

                                </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <!-- end container -->
        </div>
        <!-- end navigation -->
    </nav>
```

**css**

```css
  body {
background: url(../images/bg.JPG)no-repeat;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }
 /* jumbotron */


 .jumbotron {
background-color: black;
opacity: 0.9;
filter: alpha(opacity=90);
/* For IE8 and earlier */
 }
 /* custom elements */


 .clearfix {
clear: both;
 }
 /* html */

ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }
 /* navigation */


 #primary {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
height: 75px;
 }

 #primary ul li {}

 #primary ul li a {
color: #FFF;
 }
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to add your CSS code.

Comment: I have added css code

Comment: Can you also post a jsfiddle or Stack Snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Never used either. I have a link to show you what i want it to look like under every one http://gyazo.com/0fbee8a859bd301f2978ac21ae1a5e19

Comment: Then if i was on the about one it would highlight

Comment: For Stack Snippets, there should be a button in the Stack Overflow markdown editor (what you see when you edit a post) that when you click it, presents you with four panels: HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and the result. Just put your code in each of the panels (depending on the type) so that others can reproduce the problem easily. Make sure that the result demonstrates the same problem that you are asking about.

Comment: I am unable to complete that process because my code character length is too long sorry

Comment: You don't need to post your entire code. Just post the minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem. Basically, ask yourself: If I were trying to solve this myself, what would code would I *absolutely need* to see the problem and be able to fix it. You can also read [how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Okay thanks for your help i have tried to skim down my code but my bootstrap js file is 6000 characters so not allowed thank you very much :)

Comment: No problem. Just include bootstrap with a link tag instead. No need to copy the whole library here.

Comment: I somehow fixed it very easily. I made a mistake :p must be tired im sorry for your time

Comment: Great. Just take this as a future reference then. ;)